# i have api in .net core with tokken authentication.i want to add feature to request api without tokken

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, microservices, asp.net-core-webapi

This API on .net core 6 and vue.js  .And I want to create a micro Service same .net 6 and vue but Independent.THAT have a key to access that to send request .net core API With their key Not Tokken.They have  the Same User.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?